# CSS and (or?) shortcode loading slow with LiteSpeed Cache

Tags: css, wordpress, caching, shortcode, litespeed

I have used this code:

```
form .this-class input[type="radio"]
{
position: fixed;
opacity: 0;
pointer-events: none;
}
```

And the radio button is hidden when I load the page without caching. But when I turn on Litespeed Cache the radio button is shown for a split second before the CSS kicks in. I tried to turn off cache on that specific page where the CSS is supposed to be active, but it ain’t working.

The form which is affected is implemented through a shortcode (Contact Form 7).

Suggestions?